# Are routing and sorting incompatible in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, routes

I followed [a tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular) as a guide in setting up table sorting in my app and it works great.  For reference, my clickable column headers are like:

```
<td>
  <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'">
    Name 
    <span ng-show="sortType == 'name'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
  </a>
</td>
```

Then I converted my app to use routing.  My navigation links look like:

```
<a href="#menuitem">
  <span>Menu item</span>
</a>
```

and my router like:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "theItem.inc"
})
.when("/menuitem", {
    templateUrl : "theItem.inc"
})
....
```

Now when I click a header, the content of the ng-view disappears.

If I change the anchors to spans (which obviates the need for the href), it works again but I lose the clickable affordance of the anchor.  I could go add a class and a style for that but I wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: Please provide some codes or a working example of what you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, [`<a>` tags are actually directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a), not standard anchor tags. You probably would want to used a styled div, or button.

However, if you want to keep the `<a>` tag, its often recommended to try removing the `#` or removing the `href` in some variation:

```
<a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'name'">
<a href ng-click="sortType = 'name'">
<a ng-click="sortType = 'name'">
```

Some browsers react differently than others, so you would want to see which works in your situation.

Comment: Thanks.  I conclude that the tutorial is flawed in including the `href` since that makes the example incompatible with routing but leaving off the `href` or using a `<span>` works for me.